# Finding an ordered basis to diagonalize Transpose matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

We define $T : M_{n \times n}R \to M_{n\times n}R$ by $T(A) = A^t$.

We can write the matrix representation of this transformation as:

$[T]_\beta^\beta = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$.

However, we also want to find an ordered basis $\beta$ for the space $M_{2 \times 2}$ such that this matrix representation $[T]_\beta^\beta$ is diagonal.

How could we do this? Would we somehow use the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of this matrix? I know the eigenvalues are $\pm 1$ and the eigenvectors are $A$ itself (the symmetric matrix) and $-A$ (the matrix with entries that are opposite of A).

Would we somehow use the diagonalization formula $A = QDQ^{-1}$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could definitely get a valid answer using the diagonalization formula.  However, I find that for questions like these, it's easier to find the eigenvectors with an "educated guess".

In particular, try the basis
$$
\left\{
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0},
\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1},
\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0},
\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}
\right\}
$$

Comment: Is there a way I could extend this to an $n \times n$ case? Would I prove this by induction? Is there a pattern to arises in terms of how to choose an ordered basis? I'll try out the diagonalization formula to see if I get the same (or similar) answer as yours! You always answer my questions so thank you :)

Comment: The easiest way to extend this is to think in terms of symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices

Comment: And you're welcome!

Comment: OH! The ordered basis you provided in the $2 \times 2$ consists entirely of symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices. Having  just one entry on the top left or the bottom right is a symmetric matrix when you take the transpose. Having an entry in a row requires you to also have the exact entry in the corresponding position in the column for a symmetric matrix and for a skew-symmetric matrix there is one entry in a row and the corresponding position in the column must have the negative of it!

Answer (score 0):

Another point of view: $T$ is a permutation s.t. $T^2=I$. Then $T$ decomposes in a product of cycles of order $2$. To use this fact, we choose the canonical basis with the following order: $E_{1,1},\cdots,E_{n,n}$ and for any $i<j$ the couple $E_{i,j},E_{j,i}$ (no matter about the order). Finally, the associated matrix is $diag(I_n,U_1,\cdots,U_{\binom{n}{2}})$ where $U_k=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$.